# Using pickle to store cookies in a selenium browser session. Gmail opens with the intended account logged in, but account not showing up in googleauth

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, pickle

I am using selenium undetected chrome for automating certain tasks. I need to log into multiple websites where I have signed up using my google account, so I want to login to my google account once and then use that account to login to other websites through "login with google" option.

This is the script I wrote to save cookies from google:

```
import pickle
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    email = "MY_EMAIL"
    password = "MY_PASSWORD"

    browser = uc.Chrome(
        options=options,
    )
    browser.get('https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/)

    browser.find_element(By.ID, 'identifierId').send_keys(email)

    browser.find_element(
        By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#identifierNext > div > button > span').click()

    password_selector = "#password > div.aCsJod.oJeWuf > div > div.Xb9hP > input"

    WebDriverWait(browser, 50).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, password_selector)))

    browser.find_element(
        By.CSS_SELECTOR, password_selector).send_keys(password)

    browser.find_element(
        By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#passwordNext > div > button > span').click()

    time.sleep(50)

    cookies = browser.get_cookies()

    pickle.dump(cookies, open("cookies.pkl", "wb"))
```

Now to use the saved cookies:

```
import pickle
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':

    browser = uc.Chrome()
    browser.get('https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2')

    cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))

    for cookie in cookies:
        cookie['domain'] = ".google.com"
        
        try:
            browser.add_cookie(cookie)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    #browser.get('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox')
    browser.get('https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f')

    google_login = WebDriverWait(browser, 5000).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located(( By.CLASS_NAME, 's-btn__google' ))
    )
    
    google_login.click()

    time.sleep(120)
```

Now, when I open gmail using `browser.get('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox')` it opens with my account already logged in, but any other website which uses google sign in option doesn't show my account logged in.

What do I need to do to make my account visible in google sign in option?

Thank you for your time...

Comment: while google can read their own cookies, 3rd party sites can't.  Chances are you need "remember me" cookies for each site which would allow that site to know that you have logged in with a google account in the past.

Comment: @pcalkins thanks for the reply. I kind of understand what's happening here. So, if I login to Google once (in the social login workflow) next time I shouldn't need to if I save those cookies as well? Is there some way of extending the expiry of those cookies? Or is there a better way of doing what I intend to do? Which is basically login to Google once and and use Google to login to all other websites.

Comment: not sure those tokens ever expire unless they are revoked... (though they will change)  But you need to have logged in to those 3rd party sites using the google account in the past.  (They do not ever see Google's cookies or the client cert in chrome... they can only see their own cookies.)  It's better to just re-login to those sites, and/or use an existing profile that's already logged in.  From a fresh profile, you won't have the initial cookies when navigating there, so a new session will probably begin before you are able to set the old session cookies which may affect remember me tokens.